# PHP: Side-effects of assigning an array element variable by reference

Tags: php, reference, variable-assignment, internal, assign

I would like to know how the side effects of assigning a PHP variable by reference works under the hood (note, I am asking about variable assignment, not passing an argument by reference to a function; like in C++, the two can be different, and PHP has programmed these two operations separately under the hood).

Basically, I am seeking an explanation for the following:

```
$a = array(111, 222, 333);
$dummyReferenceVariable = &$a[0];
$b = $a;
$b[0] = "change everything: both a[0] and b[0]";
```

After the dummy variable is created, assigning to `$b[0]` will alter `$a[0]`, even if the `$dummyReferenceVariable` is never used. Why?

Comment: Please don't post an incomplete question.

Comment: http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html is a good start

Comment: So it looks like you're trying to formulate a canonical question/answer pair. For that to be of use, the _question_ has to be good as well as the answer. The question as you have asked it is too broad, and in immediate danger of being closed.

Comment: I think my answer is relatively complete. Please let me know if I've omitted any important details, or if it can be improved. Thanks.

Comment: If you can edit the question to make it specific, it may survive closure or be a candidate for reopening if it does get closed.

Comment: OK, I think I'm done editing the question. Please have a look and let me know if everything's OK.

Comment: @JohnSonderson Yes, I think that's a good question. I'll keep an eye on it and if it gets closed, I'll vote to reopen. It has 3 pending closevotes now, so it is quite possible it will get closed despite the improvements.

Answer (score 2):

To see how such side effects work, consider the following snippet:

```
$a = array(111, 222, 333);
$b = $a;
$b[0] = 999;

var_dump($a, $b);

$dummyReferenceVariable = &$a[0]; 

$dummyReferenceVariable = 444;

var_dump($a, $b);

$c = $a;
$d = $b;

var_dump($a, $b, $c, $d);

$a[0] = 555;
$b[0] = 666;
$c[0] = 777;
$d[0] = 888;

var_dump($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

I will illustrates what happens under the hood with the following diagrams (what happens internally when arrays are assigned-by-value is already covered by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280833/when-you-assign-by-value-an-array-variable-in-php-is-the-array-really-deep-copi)), whose example in its answer starts the same as this one although the question asked is a different one:

NOTE: In the diagrams **orange links** behave such that when the array the pointing array element belongs to is assigned, the corresponding array element in the array copy will point to the same location with **copy-on-write disabled**. On the other hand, **black links** indicate that when an array element is assigned the value will be copied to a new memory location (**copy-on-write**):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Just to make my point, here is the program's output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(111)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(999)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &int(444)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(999)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &int(444)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(999)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &int(444)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(999)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &int(777)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(666)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &int(777)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(888)
  [1]=>
  int(222)
  [2]=>
  int(333)
}
```

---

---

Note. This peculiarity only takes place when assigning references to array elements, as the following straightforward snippet confirms:

```
// ASSIGNING REFERENCE VALUES TO SCALARS (INSTEAD OF ARRAY ELEMENTS) WORK AS EXPECTED:

$a = 111;
$aRef = &$a;

$a = 222;
var_dump($a, $aRef); // 222, 222

$aRef = 333;
var_dump($a, $aRef); // 333, 333

$c = $a;
$d = $aRef;

$c = 444;
$d = 555;

var_dump($a, $aRef, $c, $d); // 333, 333, 444, 555
```

which outputs the following as expected:

```
int(222)
int(222)
int(333)
int(333)
int(333)
int(333)
int(444)
int(555)
```

Here is what happens under-the-hood in the above scalars case:

[image]